# Windows 10, Git Bash - bash: git: command not found

Tags: windows, bash, git, windows-10

Git Bash no longer recognizes `git` commands, as well as some commands like `ls` and `env`. I've checked that the following paths were set up in my environment variables and I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling git.

Paths that are present:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\bin

C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
```

I would like to note that I am only having this issue with Git Bash. I've tried using `git` commands through Command Prompt, and everything seems to work there.

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` print in git-bash? Are these paths in the output?

Comment: it show $HOME/.local/bin:C:UsersiserrAppDataRoaminglocalbin

Comment: Edit `~/.bashrc` in git-bash and append `export PATH=$PATH:/c/Program\ Files/Git/bin:/c/Program\ Files/Git/cmd`. Reopen git-bash and try `git`, `ls` and 
 `env`.

Comment: all of the git commands work! but ls and env are still a no go

Comment: Try `export PATH=$PATH:/c/Program\ Files/Git/bin:/c/Program\ Files/Git/cmd:/c/Programe\ Files/Git/usr/bin`. Maybe just use `export PATH=$PATH:/c/Program\ Files/Git`.

Comment: everything works now! Thank you!!

Comment: @IreneSerrano Want to add an answer? If not, I may add a community wiki answer so it shows resolved.

Comment: Or @ElpieKay since you solved it.