# bash: ls: command not found

Tags: windows, bash, windows-10, git-bash

This is my first time using GitBash. Faced a problem when GitBash couldn't find my python:

$ python --version
bash: python: command not found

Then I tried to fix it with:

export PATH='$PATH:/c/Users/usr/anaconda3'

After that python commands started to work but some other were lost:
$ ls
bash: ls: command not found

Found one simmilar case but didn't quite understand what I have to do
[Windows 10, Git Bash - bash: git: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66129948/windows-10-git-bash-bash-git-command-not-found)

Comment: You need to use double quote export PATH="$PATH:/c/Users/usr/anaconda3"

Comment: After installing have you restarted git-bash?

Comment: @koolwithk is correct: you broke your PATH setting by making it contain the literal string `$PATH`, rather than the value of the previous `$PATH` plus the `/c/User/usr/anaconda3` directory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39795766/how-to-edit-corrupted-bash-profile

Answer (score 0):

Hey pretty sure you need to do it without the quotes:
export PATH=$PATH:/c/Users/usr/anaconda3

See image:
[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Fckk.png)

Anyway, after restarting gitbash the PATH variable should revert to its default value.
If it doesn't i suggest adding the following to the path:

```
/c/Users/<YOUR_HOSTNAME>/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin
```

Comment: That really helped, thanks a lot!